# Invert colors of the active window

Tags: xorg, colors, window-manager

Sometimes I work in low light and I need to invert the color of specific windows to reduce my eye strain. This could be my pdf viewer to web pages for reference work.

I know how to invert the entire screen:

```
xcalib -invert -alter
```

But I can't find any man pages, docs or posts how to invert *a single window only*. I did this before yet cannot find how. Bizarre!

Searching the repos for other xorg tools I found xpdf, it has invert support but won't help for anything other than viewing pdf's. I don't use compositing so please don't suggest Compiz. I use Openbox WM. Thanks all.

**Update**

Instead of a general all-purpose tool to invert any window, I focused my search on how to invert colors for a Google Chrome tab instead. I found [Color Bookmarklets](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/color.html), you drag them to the browser toolbar and hit them to change the page content to invert the colors (invert lightness).

Comment: I find KWin+Compiz (e.g. with KDE) to do job of inverting colors of selected (active) windows perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a method universal for any window, then this must be made available by the window manager. Therefore I'm afraid any non-composite WM will not be able to do that on demand. So maybe you previously did this with Compiz?

A method of inverting colors regardless of WM is doing this per-application - as with `xpdf` that you mentioned. There are some applications that have such functionality, but usually you won't be able to invert the colors at run-time. For apps like `xpdf`, you can either have an alternative desktop menu entry (or icon) that runs the app with special parameters, or define those in your `.Xdefaults`. For `xpdf` note also the use of `paperColor`, `foreground`  and `background` resources.

Comment: I did have Compiz on one of the desktops at the time IIRC, perhaps I did just confuse the Compiz invert window function with that of another tool. +1 for the mention of .XDefaults resources

Answer (score 3):

I found a tool called [compton](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/README.md) in an answer to a similar question.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/134668/how-to-trigger-a-color-inversion-effect-for-one-window

Answer (score 0):

KWin with Compiz are doing this!
(Still I have since some time to reenable "Composing" after each reboot with "Alt+Shift+F12" - at least that's shortcut I have under System Settings → Shortcuts → Global Shortcuts → Kwin)

Actually I really need inverting color of specific windows (not whole screen) and that's main reason why I often choose KDE -> it has build in support for this!

You go in System Settings → Desktop Behaviour → Desktop Effects → Invert and you click on settings for **Invert** effect and select convenient shortcut (I selected long one, as I mapped it on my Kinesis Keyboard under Capslock as I invert colours very often for my eyes...).

[image: Settings of Invert Desktop Effect under: System Settings → Desktop Behaviour → Desktop Effects → Invert]

P.S. It seems there some people managed to marry [KWin e.g. with Xmonad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_KDE) or [Xmonad with Compiz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxpzNGppcbs) so maybe don't have to fully switch to KDE. (Actually I have to try xmonad+kwin one day...) anyway, there are also kwin scripts to change it's behaviour like https://github.com/faho/kwin-tiling . Enjoy!